# Show that $f(x)=3x^{2}-2x+1$ is continuous at 2

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Please check my proof

Let$\delta ,\epsilon >0$

$$|x-2|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(2)<\epsilon $$

$$             \rightarrow  |3x^{2}-2x+1-3x^{2}-2x+1|<\epsilon $$

$$             \rightarrow |-4x|<\epsilon $$

$$             \rightarrow 4|-x|<\epsilon $$

$$             \rightarrow  |-x|<\frac{\epsilon }{4}$$

choose $\delta =\frac{\epsilon }{4}$

then$ 4|-x|<\frac{4\epsilon }{4}=\epsilon $

therefore it 's continuous at 2

Comment: What you write is totally wrong. What is $f(2)$?

Comment: $f(2) = 3x^2 +2x-1$? and $1+1 =0$? Huge mistakes!

Comment: Ok I sew it thank for point the mistake

Comment: Oh,I got 2 down votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is incorrect. There is a general "formula" for how these proofs should go. Whatever "$\delta$" calculations you do are in some way inessential. You should try again like so:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Suppose that $\delta=a>0$. Then $|x-2|<\delta$ **implies that** $|f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$. This asserts the existence of an appropriate $\delta$ for each $\epsilon$, which is what you need for continuity.

The "implies that" is the majority of the proof. You should plug in the function $f$ for both values, and show how your assumption on the size of $\delta$ can be used to prove the claim.

Additionally, you have made algebra errors in the "solution" for $\delta$. perhaps somebody will give a full solution, but as written, your proof is incorrect.

Comment: The question was "check my proof." I did, and offered some logical advice. Why the downvotes?

Comment: don't know I think you answer is ok

Comment: I downvoted it because the sentence "implies that $|f(x)-f(2)|$. " has no meaning!

Comment: @AlexSilva that is a good point, edited.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=3x^{2}-2x+1$, then $f(2)=3\cdot2^2-2\cdot2+1=9$. So you want to make
$$\left|f(x)-f(2)\right|=\left|3x^{2}-2x+1-9\right|=\left|3x^{2}-2x-8\right|=\left|x-2\right|\left|3x+4\right|$$
arbitrarily small given that you can make $|x-2|$ sufficiently small. Can you proceed?

---

Two typical ways to proceed to find a suitable $\delta$ as a function of $\varepsilon$:

- first bound $\delta$ (e.g. $\delta \le 1$) to get an upper bound on the factor $\left|3x+4\right|$;
- rewrite: $3x+4=3(x-2)+10$, then $\left|3x+4\right| \le 3\left|x-2\right|+10$.